# Term for manufactured drug

Tags: terminology, medications

What is the English term for a manufactured pharmaceutical drug of a specific strength and dosage form, i.e. a pill, an ointment etcetera?

Answer (score 2):

*Drug product* seems to be the correct term, see https://biorelevant.com/blog/drug-substance-vs-drug-product/.

Answer (score 0):

Most generally, you could call this a ***dose*** of a drug. This refers to a specific amount of medication taken at one time. For example, Regular and Extra Strength versions of common painkillers will have different amounts of the active ingredient, so they differ in dose. Dose only refers to the amount of a particular active ingredient, as you can't really compare "strength" of different compounds like insulin and aspirin, for example. Generally, higher doses of a drug will have a greater effect (i.e. Extra Strength painkiller is just a higher dose of Regular Strength painkiller).

Comment: As far as I understand, a dose refers to a specified amount of medication *taken* at one time (https://www.verywellhealth.com/drug-dose-definition-and-examples-1123989)

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom As I understand it, a dose is like a "unit" of medication (a pill, injection, etc.), while dosage attaches a time frequency. So your dosage of painkillers might be two 500mg doses (pills), twice a day.

Comment: Yes, but the term I'm looking for is independent of the amount.